# How to call a Java class from an Android activity?

Tags: android

This may sound like a question asked by another user, but the solution does not work for me so I would like to try asking about my code.

I have created a folder under the res directory that contains some java classes I would like to reference/ call from one of my Activities but the import does not work and the classes do not seem to be recognised.

Calling code in the Activity file:

```
//    Method to populate the screen with images

public void initializeWithCGImages(){

    ArrayList<src.cercia.batik.app.DesignUnitViewer> mapviewers,viewerList;
    ArrayList<src.cercia.batik.geometry.Population> populations;


    src.cercia.batik.app.InitializePopulation initialize=new src.cercia.batik.app.InitializePopulation();
    populations = initialize.getInitialGenes();
    mapviewers=new ArrayList<cercia.batik.app.DesignUnitViewer>();
...
}
```

Code for the reference in folder: "res/src/cercia/batik/app":

```
package cercia.batik.app;

import cercia.batik.geometry.Population;

public class InitializePopulation {
        public InitializePopulation(){

}
...
}
```

Comment: Advice: People answering questions see a long list and it is totally up to them, where they click. They decide on the tags, and on the title. On this reason you have better chance to get a useful answer, if you formulate your question title to a very clear, easily understable question, not only to some words packed together. Around so. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The res directory is for resources. Things like imaged and layouts. The compiler isn't going to look there for Java files. Move them up into your java folder.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I've moved my files into the java folder so that the path is now java/src/cercia.batik/app/<classname>.  This may be a noob question, how do I reference the classes from inside an Activity?  I tried import java.src.cercia.batik.* but it doesn't seem to work.